# Datepart - trying to understand

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have following script but i am trying to understand what -14 means here

```
 DATEPART(wk,ic.[Pick Completed DateTime]) = DATEPART(wk, getdate()-14) and  
 year (ic.[Pick Completed DateTime]) = Year(getdate()-14)
```

Comment: A good way to figure this out is to break it apart and work from the inside out, e.g.: `select ic.[Pick Completed DateTime], DATEPART(wk,ic.[Pick Completed DateTime]), getdate(), getdate()-14, DATEPART(wk, getdate()-14), ... from ...` and see what you get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SELECT GETDATE()`

gives you this result: 2017-04-20 10:44:08.043

`SELECT GETDATE() - 14`

gives you this result: 2017-04-06 10:45:33.773

notice that difference between the two dates is 14 days. The subtraction of days is not very explicit, so I would recommend changing it to this code to avoid confusion in the future:

`SELECT DATEADD(DAY, -14, GETDATE())`

Answer (score 0):

The `getdate() - 14` is the same as `dateadd(day, -14, getdate())`.  It is a shorthand for date arithmetic for `datetime`s, but not `date`s.

More relevantly.  This code is checking that the date`ic.[Pick Completed DateTime]` is from two weeks ago.  Okay, more accurately, that is from the week containing the date that is two weeks before the current time.